# How to programmatically detect if a png file is corrupted?

Tags: c#, .net

I have written a code that is saving some bitmaps in png format (using bitmap.Save() method). However for some unknown reason some of the images are saved as corrupted pngs so Photoshop cannot open them.

I need to detect these pngs in my code rather than opening them one by one in the Photoshop.

is there any way that I can read the created png and check if it is corrupted?

Comment: I have sometimes had corrupted images due to being 0 bytes, or because they contain one format but use the file extension of another. Check these two criteria first just to be sure. (Before you invest a lot of time in code that might be possible to avoid.) Just a suggestion.

Comment: Do these saved PNG files open in any viewer, other than Photoshop? If the files are really corrupted, a picture loader in C# libraries wouldn't open the files. You could try opening the file right after saving.

Comment: I should mention that Irfanview (http://www.irfanview.com) (a lightweight image viewer application) will notify you when opening a file that is of one format but specifies the incorrect extension and offers to change it.

Comment: If it's corrupted I'd say that if you try to open it using Image.FromFile might fail. Just a guess.

Answer (score 3):

Are you making sure to close your stream properly when you are done?  I think it's extremely unlikely that a Bitmap.Save() would result in a corrupted PNG or that Photoshop couldn't read any PNG created by .NET.

The easiest thing to try is to immediately load it again in .NET.  I would try to get to the bottom of why this is happening -- what is specifically corrupt about it?

Comment: thanks for this. I don't know what it is corrupted about. But I tried 

Image img = Image.FromFile(inputFile);
Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(inputFile);
bool validImage = img.RawFormat.Equals(ImageFormat.Png);

none of them throw any error!! is there any other method to load the image?

Comment: After loading it, can you do something with it? Check it's height and width -- compare a section of pixels against the original.  One thing to check is is you can load it with the WPF codecs -- they are very sensitive to corrupt files -- if they load it, it's probably not corrupt.  If Windows Vista shows a thumbnail of it, it's probably not corrupt (corrupt PNG could be a virus vector, so they won't decode it in the Explorer unless it's perfect)

Answer (score 1):

Try and read the file back into C# and catch the appropriate exception is there's an error (although you don't specify the form of corruption - a blank file for example isn't really corrupt, it's just blank!)

Comment: I don't think a zero length file is a valid PNG.

Comment: It's also not a corrupt PNG. It's just not a PNG :)

Answer (score 1):

I would try reading the file, then check the header and see whether all required "chunks" (IHDR, PLTE, IDAT and IEND) exist and contain reasonable data.

Comment: Can you send me a link to a good PNG spec document. I wasn't able to find out at which address each one of those "chunk" should strat, so don't know how to check them?!! many thanks for your help.

Comment: See http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Contents.html for the spec.  You probably want to look at sections 3 and 4.1.  There is no predefined address for the start of each chunk, but you can walk through them by using the Length field (see section 3).

Answer (score 0):

`Image.FromFile` will throw an `OutOfMemoryException` if it cannot understand the format of the file.  This strikes me as kind of an odd choice for an exception, but both empirically testing and the documentation agree that this is the exception it throws.

See [Image.FromFile Method (String) on the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5(VS.80).aspx).

Comment: I have tried these all, none throws any exception!!

Image img = Image.FromFile(inputFile);
Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(inputFile);
bool validImage = img.RawFormat.Equals(ImageFormat.Png);

Answer (score 0):

The [PNG format](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/) allows different compression, filtering, and interlacing methods. Do you have an older version of Photoshop that is perhaps not aware of newer methods?

It might be useful to examine the headers of two PNG files: One that does load, and one that doesn't.